# Magento 2 update custom column value in sales_order table in a controller file

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, sales-order, backend, custom-attributes

I have created "custom_column" in "sales_order" table and save the data using event observer.After some actions on that order again I need to change the value of my "custom_column" in a controller file. But When I use this code

```
$order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($orderId);
$order->setData('custom_column', 'No');
$this->_orderRepository->save($order);
```

But the value is not saving in to "sales_order" table.
If I use this statement I am getting the 'custom_column' value.

```
$order->getData('custom_column')
```

What mistake I am doing here ? Can I set the value by using above method ?

Comment: Which controller are you using?

Comment: Admin / Backend controller of my custom module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some other module is loading the order object and setting some data and then calling save method causing the custom column value to reset.

Try saving order object using `Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory` OR `Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order`

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order $orderResourceModel
) {
    $this->orderResourceModel = $orderResourceModel;
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
}

public function execute()
{
    $order = $this->orderRepository->get(1);
    $order->setCustomColumn('No');
    $this->orderResourceModel->save($order);
}
```

Comment: yes, another observer working on after save event and setting up the same attribute value.